# How do I load views independent of the site.master?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm preparing an application I wrote in ASP.Net MVC for some light Ajax-y stuff. Basically, I want users to be able to go to different parts of the page without it reloading.

To do this I want to be able to reload the body of my page.

My site master is broken down into a head body and foot div. I want to be able to use something like $("body").load(whateverlink) to refresh the body, but in my case doing this causes the website to be rendered inside the body.

How can I do this successfully?

EDIT: The page is made up of views, not partialviews. In theory I could go and convert all my pages to partials but I'm looking for a way around that if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get your controllers to return partial views, using JQuery to do a request and update a div with your page content:

JQuery:

```
function navigate(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Index",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       $("#content").html(html);
      }
   });
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    public void Index()
    {
       return this.PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however (technically worse) result. Now it renders a second copy of the page right below the first one. I there something I'm forgetting? If I didn't mention it, I'm trying to load a new view not partialview

Comment: @edude05 I've changed $("#content").append(html) to $("#content").html(html). That should overwrite the content of your div rather than appending the html

Comment: Thank Charlie, but so far that gives me the same result as (main).load(/controller/action). I need a way to get ASP to return my view as a partial, right now its still returning the entire page inside the div.

Comment: Is your partial view a user control? It needs to be an ASCX file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful [article](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/) on BrightMix which might help. It basically renders a partial to a string, which you could then return as part of a `ContentResult`.